Files showing up in finder but not accessible from an application
I've recently installed Sierra Charts which opens and runs fine on Wine.
The problem I have is that I cannot open a data file from Sierra, as it is not visible to Sierra. The data file is in the correct place, and it is visible in the Finder to me with correct file suffix and permissions. I know that I have put these files in the correct place because I have tried this under a different OS and it works.
Has anyone got any ideas for correcting this anomaly?
Many thanks,
Andy

The data file is in the correct place where? . I have tried this under a different OS and it works which?.

You've not yet told us what Ubuntu product and release of that product you're using; are you hoping we guess?  Why not just tell us what you're using.
